# can we represent the venn diagram on 4 sets $(A,B,C,D)$ with circular patterns.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can a venn diagram for 4+ sets not be constructed using circles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/why-can-a-venn-diagram-for-4-sets-not-be-constructed-using-circles)

can we represent the venn diagram on 4 sets $(A,B,C,D)$ with circular patterns.

Here's a venn diagram on 4 sets with elliptical patterns.[image]

Comment: See: [Question #1475](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/why-can-a-venn-diagram-for-4-sets-not-be-constructed-using-circles).

Comment: This is an exact duplicate.

Comment: Close votes reasonable, but why the downvote?

Comment: @anon Who knows.

Comment: @anon: $\;\;$ It was probably from someone who did not have enough reputation to $\hspace{1.65 in}$ vote to close. $\:$ (I have done that a few times.) $\;\;\;\;$