# Can't simplify this boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm trying to simplify this boolean expression:

$$(AB)+(A'C)+(BC)$$

I'm told by every calculator online that this would be logically equivalent:

$(AB)+(A'C)$

But so far, following the rules of boolean algebra, the best that I could get to was this:

$(B+A')(B+C)(A+C)$

All of the above are logically equivalent (I've made a truth table for each) but I don't understand what steps am I missing trying to simplify the expression.

I also couldn't find an "expression simplifier" tool online that could show me the steps that I'm missing.

Help / directions to go to would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, clearly there's either $A$ or $A'$ in the first two terms, so use this to split the third wheel up, and absorb the pieces.

$\begin{align}(AB)+(A'C)+(BC) & = (AB)+(A'C)+(A+A')(BC) \\ & = (AB)+(A'C)+(ABC)+(A'BC) \\ & = (AB+ABC)+(A'C+A'BC) \\ & = (AB)(1+C)+(A'C)(1+B) \\ & = (AB)+(A'C)\end{align}$

Comment: That was really helpful.. thanks! one question - could I have made it if I hadn't added any external (even though completely valid) literals like you did with (A+A') ?

Comment: No, it seems not, @shaqed .   Sometimes you do have to make things seem more *complex* before you can *reduce* them.  Moving around a blockage may require taking *one step back* before *two steps forward*.

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to add the following explanation to the above answers:*

> The first two terms translate as “If *A*, then *B*, else *C* ”. Notice, therefore, that *B* and *C* cannot 
>  simultaneously coexist, meaning that the third term can be safely ignored or omitted, since it 
>  is superfluous or redundant.

Comment: Very well said +1

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the consensus rule.

$BC$ is the *"consensus"* term of $AB$ and $A'C$ and can be removed or added to the boolean expression.

**Derivation**
$$(X.Y)+(X'.Z)+(Y.Z)$$
$$=(X.Y)+(X'.Z)+(X+X')(Y.Z)$$
$$=(X.Y)+(X'.Z)+(X.Y.Z)+ (X'.Y.Z)$$
$$=(X.Y)+(X.Y.Z)+(X'.Z)+(X'.Y.Z)$$
$$=X.Y(1+Z) + X'.Z(1+Y)$$
$$=X.Y + X'.Z$$

Thus $$(X.Y)+(X'.Z)+(Y.Z)= X.Y + X'.Z$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
AB+A'C+BC&=AB(C+C')+A'C(B+B')+BC\\
&=ABC+ABC'+A'BC+A'B'C+BC\\
&=(A+A')BC+BC+ABC'+A'B'C\\
&=BC+BC+ABC'+A'B'C\\
&=BC+ABC'+A'B'C\\
&=(A+A')BC+ABC'+A'B'C\\
&=ABC+A'BC+ABC'+A'B'C\\
&=AB(C+C')+A'(B+B')C\\
&=AB+A'C
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Though this has already some good answer, I know an interesting way to look at boolean expression with less than 4 elements(for greater than 3 it becomes [messy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/why-can-a-venn-diagram-for-4-sets-not-be-constructed-using-circles) ),it might be helpful for any future user struggling with a similar problem.

Imagine them as Venn diagrams, draw their intersection using the given expression, after this most of the time question becomes trivial.

You can easily see/confirm A'C +AB covers the colored region completely.

(ignore my drawing skills)
[image: ignore my drawing skills]