# Proof writing involving Boolean algebra: AB' + AC + BC

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

How?

**AB' + AC + BC ≡ AB' + BC**

RS

≡ AB' + AC + BC

≡(AB' + A)(C + BC)

≡ AC

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534246) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick test with truth values would show that what you have cannot be right: if $A$ is false and $C$ is true, $AC$ is false, but $AB'+BC$ is true when $B$ is true.

$$\begin{align*}
AB'+AC+BC&\equiv AB'+A(B+B')C+BC\\
&\equiv AB'+ABC+AB'C+BC\\
&\equiv(AB'+AB'C)+(ABC+BC)\\
&\equiv AB'+BC
\end{align*}$$

Comment: OMG im so dumb!

Comment: Can this be translated to operation "Sets" in the similar way?

Comment: @Steve: Don’t worry: we’ve all felt that way on occasion! \\ You mean with intersection, union, and complement? Yes.

Comment: Just to make sure, (A∩B')∪(A∩(B∪B′)∩C)∪(B∩C), this statement is valid and will yield (A∩B′)∪(B∩C) as well right?

Comment: @Steve: Yes, using essentially the same sequence of steps.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much :) have a really good night!

Comment: @Steve: You’re welcome; you too!