# Is this a correct Venn Diagram for 4 sets? (Not circles)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, solution-verification

I was just playing around with GeoGebra, then I tried to represent four sets $A, B, C, D$ using triangles. It seems correct to me, but I want your confirmation.

If not correct, I hope you bother to state the reason.

[image]

Comment: I don't think so.  There should be $16$ regions, and I only count $13$.  I may have miscounted, but I don't think I've missed $3$.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the regions are.  It looks like $EDB$, $ACB$, $GIH$ are some of them... but what else?  $DCJ$?  I only see $12$ regions, $13$ if you count outside of the entire image... With four sets there should be $2^4=16$ regions.

Comment: Related: [Why can a venn diagram for 4+ sets not be constructed using circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/why-can-a-venn-diagram-for-4-sets-not-be-constructed-using-circles)

Comment: I've added a new photo, stretched out stuff and added more points. I believe there are 16 regions If my method of counting is correct. Can you check again?

Comment: Did you mean V**e**nn diagram?

Comment: I did. Do you have an answer to my question?

Comment: I still count $13$ regions including the outside region.  You have not yet clarified which portions of the figure correspond to which set... but if I was right that $DCJ$ is meant to be the "blue" set... then where does the "blue" set overlap with the orange?

Comment: It doesn't. I think that proves my construction is not correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: But I have a question, If we picked J on GH, would that make the construction correct?

Comment: Then where would blue overlap with black and orange without overlapping with red at the same time?  Place $J$ even a bit further below $GH$.  I think that might fix it... it is hard to tell without seeing it.  Still, this construction is hardly convenient.  The constructions alluded to in the linked question are much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the Comments, you're missing various regions. Here's one with 4 triangles that does work.  I tried to use 1 right angled (blue), 1 isosceles (red), 1 equilateral (green), and 1 scalene (black) triangle, so you can use this Venn diagram to classify various triangles. :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I have a question. How do we count regions? I just count everything in which borders are lines we drew. Is this method correct? or do we just brainstorm every set that can be constructed from 4 sets? Is there a systematic way to do this?

Comment: @HassanAshraf This diagram has 16 regions, corresponding to the 16 possibilities of either being inside or outside each of the triangles. Note that one of those possibilities is to be outside of all the four triangles. so that's the 'outside' region ... which isn;t really 'bordered by anything.  It took a bit of trial and effort to draw the triangles so that you indeed get these 16 regions, thoguh there is a basic method for this: (continued)

Comment: @HassanAshraf The basic method is this: start with one enclosed figure. Then draw a second one that goes inside the first and out. Then a third that follows that same trajectory that the second did, but that crosses the second one exactly once  before the second one makes any crossing. The fourth now follows *that* trajectory, but corsses the third one exactly once between any crossings that the third one makes. Etc. (continued)

Comment: @HassanAshraf If you can make the enclosed figures flexible, you can *always* do this, meaning that a Venn diagram is possible for *any* $n$. But with constraints on the figures, a Venn ddigram made of those figures may become impossible. Apparently you can make a Venn diagram out of 6 triangles, but probably making one for 7 triangles is impossible, juts like a Venn diagram made of 4 perfect circles is impossible.

Comment: So we count any geometric figure in the diagram, plus the outside region. Doesn't matter whether it is convex or concave, regular or not. Am I right? 
For example, do we count DMG, DGPJM as regions or not?

Comment: @HassanAshraf DMG Yes.  DGPJM No.  DGPJM consists of 2 regions: DMG and GPJM